# Dynamically Changing Keyboard Type for a UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar

I have an iPhone app that uses a `UISearchBar` and `UISearchDisplayController`.  The search bar has three scope buttons.  I would like the keyboard to be a numeric keypad when a particular scope button is selected, but be a default keyboard when any other scope button is selected.

I have implemented the `UISearchBarDelegate` `selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange:selectedScope` method as follows:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange:(NSInteger)selectedScope
{
    switch (selectedScope) {
        case DeviceIDScopeIndex:
            searchBar.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
            break;
        default:
            searchBar.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
            break;
    }
}
```

I know that the method gets called, and the right case gets triggered when the button in question is selected.  But the onscreen keyboard doesn't change unless I tap the Cancel button to hide the keyboard, then tap the search field again to bring up the keyboard again.

Is there a way to get the keyboard to change itself while it's onscreen, or to programmatically hide it and then reshow it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you're using iOS 3.2 or newer, you can call:

```
[searchBar reloadInputViews]
```

and it switches immediately without hackery. At least this works for me on a UITextField. (I mention this because the resign/become first responder trick didn't work exactly right for me, but reloadInputViews did.)

Comment: FYI, [searchBar reloadInputViews] doesn't work in most places Xcode 4.2 for iOS 5.0.1.  The keyboard type used is the one specified in the storyboard and I can only change the keyboardType within (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)aSearchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText.  I've tried changing it in the VDL, after the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, nothing matters.

Comment: I find a drawback on this: if the user is typing both numbers and letters, calling this method will automatically switch to letters keyboard, even though he wants to keep typing numbers

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Resigning and setting first responder can have unintended side effects.

Comment: unfortunately (2019) this does not work for me - you seem to have to resign/become.  Yes, you have to take care in your text entry handling code.

Answer (score 23):

Even though this is kind of a hack, this worked for me:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange:(NSInteger)selectedScope {


    switch (selectedScope) {
    case 0:
       searchBar.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
        break;
   default:
        searchBar.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
        break;


    // Hack: force ui to reflect changed keyboard type
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    [searchBar becomeFirstResponder];

}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I figured this would be the solution, but hoped for something less "unclean."

Comment: Funny enough, if you call resignFirstResponder and becomeFirstResponder immediately after each other the keyboard switches without dismissing

Answer (score 1):

```
[searchBar reloadInputViews]
```

and

```
[searchBar resignFirstResponder];
[searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
```

both can work, but the second method have more side effect, change firstResponder, can trigger keyboard's notification, so may affect other logic which depends on the keyboard's notification, and affect the view's frame which depend on keyboard frame's change