# iPhone UISearchBar & keyboardAppearance

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uisearchbar

When the keyboard appears, I want to set the

```
keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert
```

I've checked the documentation and it looks like you can only change the keyboardType.

Can this be done without violating any of Apple's private API's ?

Answer (score 35):

The best way that I found to do this, if you want to do it throughout your app, is to use Appearance on UITextField. Put this in your AppDelegate on launch.

```
[[UITextField appearance] setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceDark];
```

Comment: Thats did it for me too. On iOS7. Albeit the category idea, below, looks good.

Answer (score 27):

This should do it:

```
for(UIView *subView in searchBar.subviews)
    if([subView isKindOfClass: [UITextField class]])
        [(UITextField *)subView setKeyboardAppearance: UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
```

didn't find any other way of doing...

Comment: I confirm: it works :o) I didn't find any other way to get it. This answer should be accepted.

Comment: I guess this works, but I found a different, simpler solution over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594346/dynamically-changing-keyboard-type-for-a-uisearchbar

Comment: @ecotax: you're linking to a solution about the keyboardType (default, ASCII, Numbers…), but this is about the keyboardAppearance (light, dark)

Answer (score 9):

This no longer works on iOS 7 because the UISearchBar view hierarchy has changed. The UITextView is now a subview of the first subview (e.g. its in the `searchBar.subviews[0].subviews` array).

A more future proof way to do this would be to check recursively the entire view hierarchy, and to check for `UITextInputTraits` protocol rather than `UITextField`, since that is what actually declares the method.  A clean way of doing this is to use categories. First make a category on UISearchBar that adds this method:

```
- (void) setKeyboardAppearence: (UIKeyboardAppearance) appearence {
    [(id<UITextInputTraits>) [self firstSubviewConformingToProtocol: @protocol(UITextInputTraits)] setKeyboardAppearance: appearence];
}
```

Then add a category on UIView that adds this method:

```
- (UIView *) firstSubviewConformingToProtocol: (Protocol *) pro {
    for (UIView *sub in self.subviews)
        if ([sub conformsToProtocol: pro])
            return sub;

    for (UIView *sub in self.subviews) {
        UIView *ret = [sub firstSubviewConformingToProtocol: pro];
        if (ret)
            return ret;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

You can now set the keyboard appearance on the search bar in the same way you would a textfield:

```
[searchBar setKeyboardAppearence: UIKeyboardAppearanceDark];
```

Comment: thanks, very helpful! I think there's a small typo though: "[sub subviewConformingToProtocol:pro]" should be "[sub firstSubviewConformingToProtocol:pro]"

Answer (score -2):

keyboardAppearance is a property of the UITextInputTraitsProtocol, which means that the property is set via the TextField object.  I'm not aware of what an Alert Keyboard is, from the SDK it's a keyboard suitable for an alert.

here's how you access the property:

```
UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
myTextField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
```

Now when the user taps the text field and the keyboard shows up, it should be what you want.

Comment: You missed the fact that this is coming from a UISearchBar and not a UITextField.

The UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert has a transparent background, which I want to keep the same throughout all of my app.  This can be achieved as you have demonstrated on UITextFields, however the UISearchBar also has a text field inside it.  I wanted to know if it is possible to set the keyboard appearance for this text field.

Comment: My bad.  In the docs, it looks like there isn't a property or method to set keyboard transparency on the UISearchBar class.  You can only set keyboard type.