# How do you change the keyboardAppearance for a searchbar in swift?

Tags: swift, uisearchbar, uikeyboard, tvos, uisearchcontroller

So, I've seen code to do it in Objective-C using `.setKeyboardAppearance`, but I can't find any equivalent in swift. I'm working on a tvOS project and using the searchController as per the tutorial. I'm trying to adjust the keyboard and have something like this

```
searchController!.searchBar is UITextInputTraits  // returns true
var searchInput = searchController!.searchBar as UITextInputTraits
searchInput.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearance.Dark //error
```

The issue is that whenever I try to make the assignment I get
`Cannot assign to property: 'searchInput' is immutable` even though I initialized it with var. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! It's a pretty...inelegant solution. You basically have to use the interface display window (the debug option before Simulate Location) and find out how many children views deep the `UISearchBarTextField` is.

**edit:** So this assumes the structure will always be the same, which isn't guaranteed. It's possible to recursively check the subviews to find the `UITextField`, but that assumes there's only 1. Essentially there is no surefire away aside from Apple creating a function to reliably return the field, so instead of going the recursive function route, I just made this optional as suggested.

```
let theBar:UITextField? = searchBar.subviews[0].subviews[0].subviews[0] as? UITextField
theBar?.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearance.Dark
```

Comment: That's not only inelegant, it's also very dangerous. You are assuming the text field will ALWAYS be 3 levels deep and always the first subview, and then forcing a cast of whatever view is there to a text field, if Apple changes it, your app will crash. If that's the only way, I'd suggest you traverse the view hierarchy to find the text field, or at least cast it as optional to avoid a crash.

Comment: Very good point! Thanks for catching my potentially dangerous brain fart. I've adjusted my code

Comment: I just found this answer which I think would be better. The idea is to use UIAppearance to change the keyboard appearance. If you don't want to override the appearance on the whole app you can use `appearanceWhenContainedIn:`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19102086/725628