# changing keyboard type during iPad UITextField entry?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

In Canada, our Postal Codes are of the form ANA NAN where A is alphabetic (A-Z) and N is numeric (0-9). Entering these values on the iPad can be painful since the user is constantly shifting to the numeric keyboard and back.

I tried changing the keyboard style as each character was entered, but the keyboard is set when first responder is set.

Does anyone know how I can make this type of data entry easier for the user? Many Thanks.

Comment: ...I can't think of any way other than to write your own keyboard, which I'm sure is something you're not too keen on doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good question, and entering postal codes is also painful for the UK - we don't even have the benefit of a standard format!

You could resign and re-set first responder on the text field but that would look horrible with the keyboard bouncing up and down. Alternatively, you could create an input accessory view with the numeric buttons, this would appear on top of the keyboard like a standard number row. The horribleness of this would depend on how well you matched the buttons to the existing keyboard buttons.

Comment: yes. I feel your pain. I think you need a PhD to figure out UK postal codes :)

Answer (score 1):

```
searchBar.keyboardType = <somehow determine needed type>;

// Hack: force ui to reflect changed keyboard type
[searchBar resignFirstResponder];
[searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
```

I wish I could take credit for this one, but all the glory belongs to Heiko Behrens. I just copy and pasted his code for your convenience.

[reference post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594346/dynamically-changing-keyboard-type-for-a-uisearchbar)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to solve this problem. It is not as elegant as building your own keyboard but it works well for my use case. Basically, I just throw a second numeric keyboard up on the screen when I need to do postal codes. See attached image. Your milage may vary.

[image: screen shot with postal code numeric keypad display]