# Programmatically changing keyboard type on iOS does nothing

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uikeyboardtype

I want to change keyboard type from default to numeric after user pressed return button.
However after setting keyboardType property nothing happens.

My code:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation];

    return YES;
}
```

I have set myself as text field delegate and the method is being called after pressing return button.

EDIT: Solved by

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation];
    [textField reloadInputViews];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301018/programmatically-change-uitextfield-keyboard-type

Comment: You might want to try the solution posted in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594346/dynamically-changing-keyboard-type-for-a-uisearchbar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically change UITextField Keyboard type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301018/programmatically-change-uitextfield-keyboard-type)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation];
    [textField reloadInputViews];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: @Kladimir if any answer helps and perfectly answers your question you should mark it as accepted using the correct sign below the answer points and vote arrows.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the Text Input Traits section under the Attributes 
inspector.